# How can I solve the discrete algebraic Riccati equations?

Tags: matrix-equations, control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control

I have heard that Schur decomposition

$$A = USU^{-1}$$

can be used to solve discrete algebraic Riccati equations 
$$X = A^T X A -(A^T X B)(R + B^T X B)^{-1}(B^T X A) + Q$$
and also continuous algebraic Riccati equations

$$A^T X + X A - X B R^{-1} B^T X + Q = 0$$

Those can be used to solve the LQR optimal cost function

$$J = \int_{0}^\infty \left( x^T Q x + u^T R u \right) dt$$

But I really don't know how to do that. Do you know. Let's assume that we have our matrix $A$ and we know $U$ and $S$ from Schur decomposition.

Answer (score 5):

I think you might be referring to what is also covered in the paper referenced by the documentation of the matlab function [dare](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/care.html#bq1mz_p-1). In that paper they call it the Schur method. This is based on adding a co-state, similar to [Pontryagin's maximum (or minimum) principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin%27s_maximum_principle).

The solution to the discrete algebraic Riccati equation (DARE) is used in the infinite horizon discrete LQR problem, which can be formulated as follows

$$
\begin{align}
\min_u & \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=0}^\infty x_k^\top Q\,x_k + u_k^\top R\,u_k \\
\text{s.t.}\, &\, x_{k+1} = A\,x_k + B\,u_k
\end{align} \tag{1}
$$

By introducing [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) this can also be written as

$$
\min_u J = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2} \left(x_k^\top Q\,x_k + u_k^\top R\,u_k\right) + \lambda_k^\top(A\,x_k + B\,u_k - x_{k+1}) \tag{2}
$$

The optimal solution can be found by setting the partial derivative of the cost function $J$ with respect to each variable to zero

$$
\left.
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial\,J}{\partial\,x_k} &= Q\,x_k + A^\top \lambda_k - \lambda_{k-1} = 0 \\
\frac{\partial\,J}{\partial\,\lambda_k} &= A\,x_k + B\,u_k - x_{k+1} = 0 \\
\frac{\partial\,J}{\partial\,u_k} &= R\,u_k + B^\top \lambda_k = 0
\end{align}
\right\} \forall\, k \geq 0 \tag{3}
$$

Solving the last for $u_k$ gives

$$
u_k = -R^{-1} B^\top \lambda_k. \tag{4}
$$

By substituting $(4)$ into the remaining equations of $(3)$ it can be shown those can be written as

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{k+1} \\ \lambda_{k}
\end{bmatrix} = \underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
A+B\,R^{-1}B^\top A^{-\top}Q & -B\,R^{-1} B^\top A^{-\top} \\
-A^{-\top}Q & A^{-\top}
\end{bmatrix}}_{\mathcal{M}_1}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{k} \\ \lambda_{k-1}
\end{bmatrix}, \tag{5}
$$

or

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{k+1} \\ \lambda_{k+1}
\end{bmatrix} = \underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
A & -B\,R^{-1} B^\top \\
-A^{-\top}Q\,A & A^{-\top}(I + Q\,B\,R^{-1} B^\top)
\end{bmatrix}}_{\mathcal{M}_2}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{k} \\ \lambda_{k}
\end{bmatrix}. \tag{6}
$$

As $k\to\infty$ both $x_k$ and $u_k$ should go to zero. Therefore $\lambda_k$ should go to zero as well, since $u_k$ is proportional to $\lambda_k$. The states $x_k$ and $\lambda_k$ can only go to zero if the initial conditions only excite stable modes of $\mathcal{M}_1$/$\mathcal{M}_2$, which can be found with the help of the Schur decomposition (the eigen decomposition could be used as well)

$$
\mathcal{M}_i = U_i\,T_i\,U_i^\top, \ \forall\,i\in\{1,2\} \tag{7}
$$

with

$$
U_i = 
\begin{bmatrix}
{}^{11}U_i & {}^{12}U_i \\
{}^{21}U_i & {}^{22}U_i
\end{bmatrix}, \tag{8}
$$

$$
T_i = 
\begin{bmatrix}
{}^{1}T_i & {}^{2}T_i \\
0 & {}^{3}T_i
\end{bmatrix}, \tag{9}
$$

such that $U_i^\top U_i = I$ and the eigenvalues of ${}^{1}T_i$ are all the eigenvalues of $\mathcal{M}_i$ which have an absolute value smaller than one. In order to be stable the initial conditions should lie in the span of the vectors associated with ${}^{1}T_i$ and thus satisfy

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_0 \\ \lambda_{i-2}
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
{}^{11}U_i \\ {}^{21}U_i
\end{bmatrix} z_0, \tag{10}
$$

such that they only excite the modes with stable eigenvalues. The value for $x_0$ can not be picked, so in order to still satisfy it one should solve for $\lambda_{i-2}$, which can be shown to yield

\begin{align}
\lambda_{i-2} &= P_i\, x_0, \tag{11} \\
P_i &= {}^{21}U_i\,{}^{11}U_i^{-1}. \tag{12}
\end{align}

By using $(7)$, combined with $U_i^\top U_i = I$ and $(9)$, then the next time step can be shown to yield

$$
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\ \lambda_{i-1}
\end{bmatrix} &= 
U_i\,T_i\,U_i^\top
\begin{bmatrix}
{}^{11}U_i \\ {}^{21}U_i
\end{bmatrix} z_0 \\
&= 
\begin{bmatrix}
{}^{11}U_i \\ {}^{21}U_i
\end{bmatrix} {}^{1}T_i\,z_0 \\
\end{align} \tag{13}
$$

From this it can be argued that any future step will remain in the span of $\begin{bmatrix}
{}^{11}U_i^\top & {}^{21}U_i^\top
\end{bmatrix}^\top$ and thus $(11)$ also should hold for all $k>0$.

---

Substituting $(11)$ into $(4)$ for $i=1$ gives

\begin{align}
u_k &= -R^{-1} B^\top \lambda_k \\
&= -R^{-1} B^\top P_1\, x_{k+1} \\
&= -R^{-1} B^\top P_1\, (A\,x_k + B\,u_k)
\end{align}

Solving this for $u_k$ gives

$$
u_k = -(R + B^\top P_1\,B^\top)^{-1} B^\top P_1\,A\,x_k, \tag{14}
$$

which matches the result from [discrete infinite horizon LQR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear%E2%80%93quadratic_regulator#Infinite-horizon,_discrete-time_LQR), so $P_1$ should also be the solution to the DARE.

Substituting $(11)$ into $(4)$ for $i=2$ gives

$$
\begin{align}
u_k &= -R^{-1} B^\top \lambda_k \\
&= -R^{-1} B^\top P_2\, x_k
\end{align} \tag{15}
$$

which should still give the same feedback gain as for $i=1$. Calculating it this way might be attractive if $R^{-1}$ can be calculated very quickly compared to $(R + B^\top P_1\,B^\top)^{-1}$, but using this does not directly give a solution to the DARE. The solution could be obtained with for example solve the following discrete Lyapunov equation

$$
(A - B\,K)^\top P\,(A - B\,K) - P + Q + K^\top R\,K = 0, \tag{16}
$$

with $K = R^{-1} B^\top P_2$.

---

For both $i=1$ and $i=2$ the matrix $\mathcal{M}_i$ uses $A^{-\top}$. This might fail if $A^{-\top}$ is singular. By reformulating is as a [generalized eigenvalue problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Generalized_eigenvalue_problem) one can still solve for ${}^{21}U_i$ and ${}^{11}U_i$. Namely the eigenvalue problem $\mu\,\vec{v} = \mathcal{M}_1\,\vec{v}$ associated with $(5)$ can also be written as

$$
\mu \begin{bmatrix}
I & B\,R^{-1} B^\top \\
0 & A^\top
\end{bmatrix}\vec{v} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
A & 0 \\
-Q & I
\end{bmatrix}\vec{v}
$$

and the eigenvalue problem $\mu\,\vec{v} = \mathcal{M}_2\,\vec{v}$ associated with $(6)$ as

$$
\mu \begin{bmatrix}
I & -A^\top \\
0 & A^\top
\end{bmatrix}\vec{v} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
(Q + I)A & -I-(Q + I)B\,R^{-1} B^\top \\
-Q\,A & I + Q\,B\,R^{-1} B^\top
\end{bmatrix}\vec{v}.
$$

These matrices can then also be used for the [generalized Schur decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition#Generalized_Schur_decomposition).

Comment: Look up the julia Control library from GitHub. There is an example how to solve riccati equations for lqr.